# Putnam 2006 solution (A2)

Tags: combinatorics

The solution to A2 of Putnams 2006 claims that for any integer $\notin B$ it must be of the form $b+p-1$ for some $b\in B$ and prime $p$ which is clear so far.

I'm confused about the existence of the integer $x$ according to the chinese remainder theorem. Why is any integer of the form $b+p-1$ a solution of the given simultaneous congruence?

Anyone mind elaborating?

Thanks

Here is a link to the 2006 Putnam: http://math.hawaii.edu/home/pdf/putnam/2006.pdf

Comment: For any $x$ there is a unique $p$ such that $x=b+p-1$, namely $p=x+1-b$. Now apply this to the special $x$ obtained by CRT.

Comment: I'm more confused by the question, what is $S$ supposed to be in the solution?

Comment: How do you know $p=x+1-b$ is prime?

Comment: @Hagen: I don't really know either what $S$ is. I assume it is a typo. But it can't be $B$ I think, so it must be $A$ the set of $n$ for which Alice wins?

Comment: Pretty sure that $S$ is just a typo for $B$, the set of positions that lose for the current player. We're then saying $m$ is not in $B$ so $m$ should be a winning position for Alice, meaning her first move has to take the pile to a value that *is* in $B$ so that Bob (whose turn it now is) loses.

Comment: In the last sentence you probably mean taking the "pile to a value to is NOT in $B$", or? Besides I think the sentence with $B$ as it stands there instead of $S$ doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative proof:
Suppose set $S$ of second-player-wins positions is finite, hence bounded by some $m$. Then for every $n>m$, there must exist a move taking $n$ to $S$, i.e., a prime $p$ with $0\le n-(p-1)\le m$. In other words, there must be a prime $p\in\{n-m+1,\ldots, n+1\}$, a set of $m+1$ consecutive integers. However, the existence of arbitraryly large prime gaps is clear, e.g., each of the $N-1$ consecutive integers  $N!+2,\ldots,N! +N$ is composite (for $N\ge 2$). So concretely, $n=(m+2)!+m+1$ must be $\in S$ while being $>m$.